# Uploading files Node.js Express put method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

I am trying to do a file upload using XMLHttpRequest, I am splitting file and chunk_size is 10KB.
On server I am using

```
app.route('/upload/').put(function(req, res, next) {

    var  buff =req._readableState.buffer[0];
    console.log('Buffer length: ' + buff.length);   
}
```

**console.log: "Buffer length: 10240"**

And I am writing file:

```
fs.write(fd,buff,0,buff.length,pos,function(){}
```

I am not using busboy, multer or body-parser
and everything works like a charm.

Then I changed chunk_size to 100KB and client is sending 100KB, I checked Content-Length.

But server is receiving 31972 Bytes and sometimes 64061 Bytes.

**console.log: "Buffer length: 31972"**

No idea what is happening, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the leading underscore of `_readableState` hints, that's not an external API and not recommended to use. Here is an excerpt of [the docs on streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_streams_under_the_hood):

> Both Writable and Readable streams will buffer data on an internal object which can be retrieved from _writableState.getBuffer() or _readableState.buffer, respectively.
>
> ...
>
> The purpose of streams, especially with the stream.pipe() method, is to limit the buffering of data to acceptable levels, so that sources and destinations of varying speed will not overwhelm the available memory.

So what happens under the hood in this case is that some of the data is put in the internal queue in the stream, waiting for consumption.

The readable stream should be consumed either with `stream.read()` and listening for `data` events, or, which should be the easiest way in this case, with the `pipe` method, like so:

```
req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("some/path"));
```

See [docs on `createWriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options).

Answer (score 0):

Its not always practical and efficient to split files this way.

You can try a node package named **files-io**.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/files-io

Hope this server your purpose.